# How to find each function specific value count in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".drugCgsts").each(function(drugCgstsIndex){
    var drugCgsts = $(this).val();
    alert("drugCgsts..."+drugCgsts);
    alert("drugCgstsIndex..."+drugCgstsIndex);
});
```

Ex:return index 0 is 6,

return index 1 is 6,

return index 2 is 12,

return index 3 is 12,

return index 3 is 5

Expected Output: 6 count is 2

12 count is 2

and 5 count is 1

Comment: Please show us your html code

Comment: This doen't make any sense.

Comment: Please share the relevant code snippet and HTML code.

Comment: I like how people edit lousy posts, make them look nicer, while OP doesn't seem to care even answering comments. Just dumps bunch of unformatted nonsense. Still people care to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all the elements with `drugCgsts` and record the unique value in a `frequency` object. Then use `Object.keys()` and `array#forEach` to access the value and its frequency.

```
var frequency = {}
$(".drugCgsts").each(function(drugCgstsIndex){
  var drugCgsts = $(this).val();
  frequency[drugCgsts] = (frequency[drugCgsts] || 0) + 1;
});

Object.keys(frequency).forEach(k => {
  console.log(k, frequency[k])
});
```